# "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" but it's not changed in the loop

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm solving [this LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/alien-dictionary) and here's my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def alienOrder(self, words: List[str]) -> str:
        adjacent = defaultdict(set)
        
        for i in range(1, len(words)):
            w1, w2 = words[i - 1], words[i]
            min_len = min(len(w1), len(w2))
            if len(w1) > len(w2) and w1[:min_len] == w2[:min_len]:
                return ""
            for j in range(min_len):
                if w1[j] != w2[j]:
                    adjacent[w1[j]].add(w2[j])  # modify, not in the loop causing error
                    break
        
        visited = dict()
        res = []
        
        def dfs(c):
            if c in visited:
                return visited[c]
            
            visited[c] = True
            for neighbor in adjacent[c]:  # read only
                if dfs(neighbor):
                    return True
            visited[c] = False
            res.append(c)
            return False
        
        for c in adjacent:  # RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
            if dfs(c):
                return ''
        return ''.join(reversed(res))
```

The line `for c in adjacent` throws "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration", which I don't understand. I'm not modifying `adjacent` in `dfs()`, am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main Problem is when dfs method is called it uses this line

```
for neighbor in adjacent[c]:
```

This just returns the associated value if it exists in defaultdict, if it doesn't exist in it, it creates and adds a key if you try to access key that doesn't exist.

Potential line that triggers accessing adjacent defaultdict without knowing whether it exist or not is

```
if dfs(neighbor):
```

neighbor might be or might not be in adjacent defaultdict this causes defaultdict to change. You might check if it exists if not u might want to skip.

Comment: But those `c`'s are from the keys in adjacent (because of the line `for c in adjacent`). The keys should already exist in the dictionary when I call `dfs(c)`.

Comment: You may do one thing instead of. For x in dict try temp= dict.keys , then for x in temp.... This will prevent the error even if the dict get modified

Comment: I know how to make it work, but I'm looking for an explanation of why this throws error. I'm checking `adjacent[c]` using keys `c` from `adjacent` itself. How does that cause an error?

Comment: Try debugging by printing adjacent dictionary at  potential place of getting edited you will eventually know

Comment: Okay so I found the culprit now. It's because when calling `dfs(neighbor)`, `neighbor` might not be in the dictionary. The first call of dfs, `dfs(c)`, is totally fine.

Comment: Can you modify your answer to include this so that I can accept it?

Comment: yes i did edit andd include what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

@gilf0yle points out the problem is with `defaultdict` *potentially* inserting new keys. The solution is to "freeze" it before iteration by casting to a normal `dict`

```py
adjacent = dict(adjacent)  # No more default key insertion from here on
for c in adjacent:
    if dfs(c):
        return ''
return ''.join(reversed(res))
```